# How to debug prepare statement with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, debugging

I am trying to insert value in my database using below code.But it does not enter value.I want to debug & print any error message i tried `$stmt->error` or `$stmt->errorInfo()` but nothing worked for me.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name) values(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", "dhieaj");

$result = $stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->errorInfo();
$stmt->close();
// Check for successful insertion
if ($result){
    // User successfully inserted
    return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
}
```

Comment: Check if your database connection was successful.

Comment: My database connection was successfull.But after $stmt->bind_param() statment there are no logs.I have matched the column names it is same.Can debug or print any error what happend after bind_param statment

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: PS: There is no such method as `$stmt->errorInfo();` as far as I am aware

Comment: Where at top ?I have class & under that class i have written this code inside a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run the same code on my Local AppEngine Server and these where my findings:

**Original Code:**

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name) values(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", "dhieaj");

$result = $stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->errorInfo();
$stmt->close();
// Check for successful insertion
if ($result){
// User successfully inserted
    return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
}
```

**Experiments:**

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", "dhieaj");  
// failed with error ( <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in <b>C:\...)
```

so I modified the line to:

```
$param="dhieaj";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
```

Next error I got was for:
    echo $stmt->errorInfo();  //(Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::errorInfo())
so I commented the line out.

Then I modified your return statement to echo since mine is just a fragment as posted by you.

I also noticed your conn lacked the '$' declaration key. ($conn).

**Final Code:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(firstname) values(?)");
$p="dhieaj";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $p);

$result = $stmt->execute();
// echo $stmt->errorInfo();
$stmt->close();
// Check for successful insertion
if ($result){
    // User successfully inserted
    echo "USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY";
}
```

Comment: I am not able to insert records.I have used conn instead of $conn because at class level i have defined $conn.

Comment: Then make sure you don't hardcode strings into bind_param() . Pass strings as variables only. Only first parameter of bind_param() should be hardcoded. @deepakkumar

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code mentioned here by 'DLastCodeBender' is correct but still i was not able to solve my issue.The issue is with **MAMP** sever.I was not able to run Slim framework with MAMP.So i installed **XAMPP** on my mac & there all API worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using MAMP. The table I was inserting to had some fields without default value. If these are not being written to in your prepared statement it will not insert the record and may not display an error.

Adding the following (as in the top comment) to the beginning of your php page will help you spot the fields that are causing the problem:

`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`